# Faster/more efficient to generate permutations of read from file?

Tags: file, generator, permutation, matching

I'm writing a program that tests a generated string against a given string to see if they match, without knowing the string or it's length. The input string cannot be manipulated either. My process so far is the brute force method of generating permutations of character sets:

Permute 'abc...xyz' for length(1+)

Until the strings match.

However, I'm wondering if it would be better or faster to generate the permutations, save them to a file, then read the lines from the file during the matching? And of course, generating the file beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability not, because in that case you would be disk IO bound, but small part of your generated code would run from cache. Code need like at most approx 10 operations to generate new permutation and is way faster than reading from disk

Answer (score 0):

It's faster and more efficient to use a [string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), like [Aho-Corasick.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Brute forcing permutations sounds terrible (performance wise). Can you give some examples, what to match? `String` sounds as if repetition would be allowed (`foo`), but `set` not so much.

To match "stack" with "tacks" more rapidly you could sort both, and check, whether they are the same, which would even work for strings, containing some characters more often:

```
 stack => ackst 
 tacks => ackst 

 hello => ehllo
 oloeh => ehloo
```

For sets, you could use regular expressions:

```
 "tacks".matches ("[stack]+")
```

if the size matches, but they would fail to match strings with repeated characters.

Comment: It's a string, not a set, sorry about that. However, I'm making it only check against the input string, there is no manipulation of the input string allowed.

Comment: Not even on a copy of the input string? You should mention that in the question.